# INDEX and MATCH return incorrect values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, lookup

There is a table in which each row is an event from the CRM system. Column A contains the IDs, and Column B contains the date and time of the event. Based on IDs, I need to calculate the duration between the next and previous events. No manipulation of tables.

| AMOCRM ID LEADS = 8952 | Date of change | Difference in hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2105687 | 2020-08-24 14:54:10 |  |
| **2104881** | **2020-08-24 14:54:11** |  |
| 2105687 | 2020-08-24 14:54:26 | 0:00:00 |
| 2105687 | 2020-08-24 14:54:28 | 0:00:00 |
| 2106409 | 2020-08-24 15:04:18 |  |
| **2104881** | **2020-08-24 15:07:29** | **0:13:18** |
| 2117085 | 2020-08-24 17:07:51 |  |
| 2117085 | 2020-08-24 17:07:53 | 0:00:00 |
| 2166941 | 2020-08-25 9:04:36 |  |
| **2104881** | **2020-08-25 9:08:13** | **18:00:44** |
| **2104881** | **2020-08-25 9:08:14** | **18:00:45** |
| 2105687 | 2020-08-25 9:08:17 | 18:13:49 |
| 2106409 | 2020-08-25 9:09:45 | 18:02:16 |
| 2106409 | 2020-08-25 9:09:48 | 18:02:19 |
| 2117085 | 2020-08-25 9:10:17 | 0:00:00 |
| 2117085 | 2020-08-25 9:10:20 | 16:02:27 |
| 2170075 | 2020-08-25 9:49:11 |  |
| 2106409 | 2020-08-25 18:32:54 | 9:23:06 |
| 2515935 | 2020-08-25 18:57:26 |  |
| 2515935 | 2020-08-26 10:28:07 | 0:00:00 |
| 2560737 | 2020-08-26 15:27:34 |  |
| 2117085 | 2020-08-27 12:25:40 | 51:15:20 |
| **2104881** | **2020-08-27 12:37:04** | **69:29:35** |
| 2117085 | 2020-08-27 15:24:54 | 54:14:34 |
| **2104881** | **2020-08-27 15:35:33** | **72:41:22** |
| 2515935 | 2020-08-31 14:54:42 | 0:00:00 |
| 2105687 | 2020-08-31 17:25:34 | 170:31:06 |

I tried this combination below and some others with the same logic

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2)>1, B2-INDEX(B$2:B2, MATCH(A2, A$2:A2, 1)), "")`

but it doesn't work correctly in some cases.
Here's the filtered sample:

[image]

Rows 3, 7, and 11 work. But in 12 (there should be 00:00:01) and 24 (there should be 51:28:50), it subtracts not the value from the previous event but from the 7 row. And in row 26 (there should be 02:58:29), it subtracts from the 3 row.

Comment: Please share the sample data not as image but as [sample sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
so we can easily reproduce the issue and better help you. Thanks!

Comment: is A2 n A3 contains the _same_ number?

Comment: No. I filtered to show where there is an issue. I added the sample without filtering to the original post for clarification.

Comment: Further to the comment by @cnavar (which seems to have been ignored). **`DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.`** Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There are several ways to include data in a markdown table including the free, online service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Great, I understand now. I apologize for any confusion I may have caused. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand. Two days ago, there was an answer but I was too busy to react. Now I can't find it. What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(or(Σ="",Λ=""),,iferror(let(Γ,counta(A2:Σ)-1, Ξ,xlookup(Σ,offset(Σ,-Γ,,Γ),offset(Λ,-Γ,,Γ),,,-1),
     if(len(Ξ),Λ-Ξ,))))))
```

- *format the `Difference in hours` column to `Duration`*
- *this works as arrayformula; so make sure the output column is devoid of any existing data/formulas so that the formula_output flows freely n' not throw an error*

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I don't know why, but it returns empty cells. I checked everything.

Comment: WOW! It works! I've just tested it with a small sample like this on 28 rows. The issue is that my data set is more than 40000 rows and it gives an error
"Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula".

Comment: Try the drag-style formula(instead of arrayformula) then. this goes into Cell_C2 (as in screenshot above) `=iferror(let(Γ,counta(A$2:A2)-1, Ξ,xlookup(A2,offset(A2,-Γ,,Γ),offset(B2,-Γ,,Γ),,,-1),
     if(len(Ξ),B2-Ξ,)))`

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance! Your help has been greatly appreciated. Moving forward, I plan to further educate myself on how the process works.

Comment: Let me ask another question. I adjusted your formula to return the difference between the current and the next events like this: `=IFERROR(LET(Γ,COUNTA(A$2:A2), Ξ,XLOOKUP(A2,OFFSET(A2,1,,Γ),OFFSET(B2,1,,Γ),,,-1), IF(LEN(Ξ),Ξ-B2,)))` , but something is wrong again.

Comment: I made it! `=iferror(let(Γ,counta(A2:A), Ξ,xlookup(A2,offset(A2,1,,Γ),offset(B2,1,,Γ),,,1), if(len(Ξ),Ξ-B2,)))`. But anyway thank you so much.